# git query file permissions of a file in an arbitrary commit

Tags: git

```
$ git init
$ date > file1.txt
$ git add .
$ git commit -a -m "ok"
$ git log --raw file1.txt
```

Last cmd works ok. I get:

```
:000000 100644 0000000... c0d0a60... A  file1.txt
```

But if I do:

```
$ git log --raw HEAD:file1.txt
```

I get nothing.

What am I missing? I need to get the second form working so that I can query the perms of the file in any arbitrary commit, not just the currently checkout working tree.

Comment: Where do you get the colon (`:`) syntax? I have never seen it.

Comment: @J-16: Read the rev-parse manpage. It describes all the syntaxes for specifying various things. It is however not valid for this particular case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The log command takes a set-of-commits and a path. In the first form you are giving it a path and set-of-commits defaults to HEAD (all commits reachable from HEAD). In the second form you are giving it an object id that does not name a commit, but is not a path either, so it can't do anything.

You need to give it a commit set and the path:

- Commit set containing just one commit is `commitish^!`. So in your case `HEAD^!`.
- Path is still just `file1.txt`

So use:

```
git log --raw HEAD^! file1.txt
```

Of course (as J-16 SDiZ correctly noted) using `git ls-tree`, which is designed for the purpose, is better than abusing `git log`. So that would be:

```
git ls-tree HEAD file1.txt
```

unlike `log`, `ls-tree` takes a treeis (of which a commitish is a special-case), so you don't have to add funny suffixes like `^!`.

Comment: also a good idea is, to separate files from the rest of the command with `--`

Comment: Is `git ls-tree -l` a better choice for this?

Comment: @J-16: Yes, definitely. I wanted to explain what's wrong with the tried command though (and didn't remember that command off the top of my head).

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
git log --raw HEAD^1..HEAD file1.txt
```

Comment: This is going to fall apart if HEAD has more than 1 parent.

Comment: @Jan Hudec, why? any parent would do.

Comment: No, all parents are needed. If you only have one parent there, than the whole ancestry through the second is listed. And that is *not* wanted here.